# How to make IE8 respect .removeClass()?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

The code that's giving me headaches is this:

```
$('#timeline .selected').removeClass('selected');
```

It just won't behave properly in IE8. The classes DO get removed properly, but somehow the element still has the same styling, just as the style with the class 'selected'.

P.S. Those two won't work either:

```
$('#timeline .selected').removeAttr('class');
$('#timeline .selected').removeAttribute('class');
```

Please help!

Comment: Check whether your element inherit similar styles from another selector.

Comment: Nope, in the inspector it shows the correct styles, but it doesn't get rendered like that. It's a simple background-position and it has the correct coordinates in the inspector, but not in the viewport.

Comment: what if you add another class that styles the element like you want?

Comment: It might be a good idea to mock up the problem on jsfiddle so that we can take a look at the strange behaviour.

Comment: Well, the super simple expample in JSFiddle is working... http://jsfiddle.net/P2zmm/  - Maybe I should try to implement the whole module in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/jWvdr/2/

```
$('li').hover( function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('active');                
});
```

---

Seems to work fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/jWvdr/

```
$('li.active').click( function() {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

What css attributes are giving you problems?

Comment: Well, this is the line of CSS that's supposed to manage the hover state and the "active" class (damnit, can't format it as code):                                              #timeline-inner section article .certificate:hover:before, #timeline-inner section article.selected .certificate:before { background-position: -232px -59px; }

Comment: That's just the attribute that I'm changing when the element has the "active" class: background-position: -232px -59px;

Comment: You are using css selector which arent fully supported by IE8. For :before and content to work in IE8, a <!DOCTYPE> must be declared. You should proberbly reconsider doing it without risky selectors :)

Comment: See if this dosen't work for you in IE8 http://jsfiddle.net/xyv8x/1/ - does for me.. So it's proberbly your CSS :)

Comment: The problem was in the :before element. IE8 doesn't respect changes in the :before if a class gets added to the main element. Thank you all!